# Is there a way I can get my spring beans wired together without having them be initialized?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Ideally, I'd like to have Spring instantiate all the beans from my context config, wire them together as specified, but never call init() on any of them. Is this possible?

Something else that might suit my needs: if there's a hook that runs after wiring but before init() is called on any of the beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `InitializingBean` to use `afterPropertiesSet` or use `@PostConstruct` to do something after construction but this doesn't guarantee it's before wiring but it doesnt sound like this is the answer you are looking for.

There is no guarantee which order Spring will initialise the beans as it has to work out the best order to initialise to deal with things like circular references etc.

Really the only way to guarantee something happens before it is wired in to another bean is to do it in the constructor.  This is why I always use constructor rather than propert/setter injection.